# Convert an optional field from (RelatedModel | undefined)[] to RelatedModel[] using filter

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble satisfying typescript in the following scenario.

```js
interface Part {
  id: number
  relatedModel?: RelatedModel
}

const parts: Part[] = [ /* list of parts ... */ ]

const relatedModels = parts
  .map(part => part.relatedModel)
  .filter(relatedModel => relatedModel)
```

Typescript thinks relatedModels has type (RelatedModel | undefined)[] but should be RelatedModel[] due to the filter. I believe what I've done is valid but Typescript isn't understanding the filter().

Is there some other way of doing this?

Note, the following works but is just a lot more verbose.

```js
const relatedModels = parts
  .map(part => part.relatedModel)

const newRelatedModels: RelatedModel[] = []

for (const relatedModel of relatedModels) {
  if (relatedModel) {
    newRelatedModels.push(relatedModel)
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's a limitation but you don't have to change your code all you need is a cast. `.filter(relatedModel => relatedModel) as RelatedModel[]`

Comment: @Eldar much appreciated. That seems like a good solution.

Comment: In addition to @Eldar's suggestion, have you tried `.filter(relatedModel => relatedModel !== undefined)`?

Comment: @Jason Yes, that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQDZ0gEwLID2OmyA3gL4CwAUDaJLIigApxRhk3LLA4BcyEAFcAtgCNoXZFEzYI%20IpgD8A9FlyFiGGlVrUEBEAGcOABzZgjA1uwDaAXWQBeZLeQB6AFTIMwE8gIYZHN2I2QAOkjkT3dkexoaA2MOGXV5TUwwlxDLKXCROFMAChznAD5gi3DUuQUtAEo8mGAMBiKimo1FDHqBTvTunjC1WoyMcuQAQkn%20usx6oA)):

```
const relatedModels = parts
  .map(part => part.relatedModel)
  .filter((relatedModel): relatedModel is RelatedModel => !!relatedModel)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!